# With Spring WebClient, how do I deserialize different types for successful and failed responses?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

**tbjorch**'s answer led me down the right path, but one thing I discovered is I should construct the HTTP exceptions using the static `.create` methods for both `HttpClientErrorException` and `HttpServerErrorException`. If I didn't do this, all my exceptions would get thrown as just the `Exception` superclass, which was undesirable since it lost the context of the original Http status code.

I am new to using Spring WebClient. The API I'm implementing responds with different JSON structures based on success or failure. In the case of a failure, I want to be able to deserialize the response body and return the error message. Based on the code below, I get an error message stating:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:83)
```

I agree, it doesn't make sense to block in 2 places. But I'm not understanding how I can deserialize the error response to grab the error message. Everything I read on the web and StackOverflow indicates people just return `Mono.error` or throw exceptions, but they don't seem to be deserializing the response body in those scenarios. Here's my code:

```
  public boolean updatePassword(String id, String data) {
    final var responseSpec =
        client
            .post()
            .uri(builder -> builder.path("/{id}/change_password").build(id))
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + staticData.getAPIToken())
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(data))
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(
                HttpStatus::isError,
                error -> {
                  final var errorResponse = error.bodyToMono(ErrorResponse.class).block();
                  final var errorMsg = errorResponse.getCause().getSummary();

                  if (error.statusCode().is4xxClientError()) {
                    throw new HttpClientErrorException(error.statusCode(), errorMsg);
                  }
                  if (error.statusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
                    throw new HttpServerErrorException(error.statusCode(), errorMsg);
                  }
                  return Mono.error(
                      new HttpServerErrorException(
                          HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Something else."));
                })
            .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});

    final var response = responseSpec.block();

    return response.containsKey("password") && response.containsKey("provider");
  }
```

**PS.** I've also tried using `.exchangeToMono` instead of `.retrieve`, so that I can inspect the response status code, and then use different types for the `.bodyToMono` function, but as soon as I write two different types between a success and failure, I get an error stating that the type argument can't be inferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that I have found a solution.

You do want to use exchange instead of retrieve as you stated. Although, You might have been missing code and that is why it didn't work for you the first time around.
By using exchange you can inspect the return codes and write to a different response object depending on the status code.

In your case,

```
final var responseSpec =
        client
            .post()
            .uri(builder -> builder.path("/{id}/change_password").build(id))
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + staticData.getAPIToken())
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(data))
            .exchange()
            .block()
 

if (respsonseSpec.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) { 
  Map<String, Object> data = 
       responseSpec.bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>() 
       {}).block()
    
   /* handle successful response  */ 

} else if (responseSpec.StatusCode().is4xxClientError()){
  ErrorResponse errorResponse = responseSepc.bodyToMono(ErrorResponse.class).block()

  /* handle error */ 
}
/*... other status code cases */
```

Hopefully this helps for deserialization to different types based on status codes

Comment: Today this doesn't work anymore; `exchange()` does not exist anymore. Any solution how this could work with `spring-webflux/6.0.10`?

Answer (score 1):

Not able to try your code exactly, but try something like this:

```java
public boolean updatePassword(String id, String data) {
    final var responseSpec =
        client
            .post()
            .uri(builder -> builder.path("/{id}/change_password").build(id))
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " /*+ staticData.getAPIToken()*/)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(data))
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(
                HttpStatus::isError,
                error -> error.bodyToMono(ErrorResponse.class)
                    .map(errorResponse -> {
                    final var errorMsg = errorResponse.getCause().getSummary();
                    if (error.statusCode().is4xxClientError()) {
                      throw new HttpClientErrorException(error.statusCode(), errorMsg);
                    }
                    if (error.statusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
                      throw new HttpServerErrorException(error.statusCode(), errorMsg);
                    }
                    return new HttpServerErrorException(
                            HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Something else.");
                  }))
            .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});

    final var response = responseSpec.block();

    return response.containsKey("password") && response.containsKey("provider");
  }
```